# Test the convergence of the series $\sum({\sum_{k=1}^{n}{\frac{1}{(n+k)^2}}}){\cos{n\theta}} $

Tags: sequences-and-series

Test the convergence of
$$\sum({\sum_{k=1}^{n}{\frac{1}{(n+k)^2}}}){\cos{n\theta}}$$
I tried as following:
Sequence of partial sums of given series is
$$\sum_{n=1}^{m}({\sum_{k=1}^{n}{\frac{1}{(n+k)^2}}}){\cos{n\theta}}=\sum_{k=1}^{n}(\sum_{n=1}^{m}{(\frac{1}{(n+k)^2})}{\cos{n\theta}})$$
Taking $m->\infty$
We have
$$\sum({\sum_{k=1}^{n}{\frac{1}{(n+k)^2}}}){\cos{n\theta}}=\sum_{k=1}^{n}(\sum{(\frac{1}{(n+k)^2})}{\cos{n\theta}})$$
Now every series on right side is convergent by Dirichlet's Test.
This implies our given series is convergent.
Is this proof OKAY?

Comment: It is not OK because $n$ is not fixed.

Comment: When $\theta=0$ the series is divergent.

Comment: Excluding the case when $\theta=0 , 2k\pi$

Comment: Then sequence of partial sums of series $\sum\cos{n\theta}$is bounded so we can apply Dirichlet's test

Comment: Yes, you can use Dirichlet test when $\theta$ is not a multilple of $2\pi$.

Comment: Is my above proof valid ?if not , please suggest how can i proceed?

Comment: By any chance are you trying to prove that fourier series of some function on $S^1$ is in $\ell^1(\Bbb Z)$ ? So that you can have some fun using Fourier inversion?